# Fine Uploader initial file list, origin of list?

Tags: fine-uploader

I understand how to respond to Fine Uploader in order to populate the file list with previously uploaded files.  However I am unsure as which event or procedure is best to follow, in order to essentially record the files a user might upload.  Initially one might retain the list of files, via the Success post.  However recording uploaded files that might have failed, or have been paused, or that were stopped.  Those list items need to be reported to the server as they happen, since there will be no Success post.  Is there a built in mechanism for this, or should I build my own, posting back to the server whatever is in the list when it changes, then recalling all of it upon the initial file list FU call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial file list should only ever be populated with files that have been successfully uploaded in a previous session.  If you are using Fine Uploader S3 (and I know you are from previous discussions) this would mean that files that have been associated with upload success calls are the only ones you should ever include in your initial file list.  How you gather the data for the initial file list is entirely dependent upon the inner workings of your application.  Presumably, you have a DB that contains metadata along with state for all uploaded files.

Comment: So is the initial file list designed to work with resuming a broken or paused upload?  Or is resuming an upload only possible when the session is preserved?  (I am keeping in mind that resuming an upload when using S3 involves using the multi-part upload feature, and it does have a time limit, I am unsure.)

Comment: The initial file list is only designed to simply display information about a file that was previously successfully uploaded in another session, and optionally allow the user to delete it from the server.  The auto resume feature kicks in when the user re-selects/submits a chunked file that failed to upload in a previous session.  The two features are unrelated.